# Mongo DB Query- sorting alphanumeric not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, nestjs

I am facing issue Not sorting material name in my query, its very straightforward and simple query, I think issue is material alphanumeric value.

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Inventory {

  @Prop({
    type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Material',
    index: true,
    required: true,
  })
  materialId: MaterialDocument;
}


@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Material {
 
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  nameAr: string;
}
```

Here is my Query

```
 const inventories: any = await this.inventoryModelPag.paginate(
  {
    ...queryToApply,
    supplierId: req.user.supplierId,
    $or: [
      { 'materialId.deletedAt': null },
      { 'materialId.deletedAt': { $exists: false } }
    ]
  },
  {
    sort: paginateOptions.sortBy
      ? {
        [paginateOptions.sortBy]: paginateOptions.sortDirection
          ? paginateOptions.sortDirection
          : -1,
      }
      : DefaultSort,
    lean: true,

    populate: [
      {
        path: 'restaurantId',
        select: {
          name: 1,
          nameAr: 1,
          _id: 1,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'materialId',
        select: {
          name: 1,
          nameAr: 1,
          _id: 1,
          category: 1,
          uomBase: 1,
          sequenceNumber: 1
        },
        match: { deletedAt: null },
        populate: [{
          path: 'uomBase',
          select: {
            name: 1,
            nameAr: 1,
            measure: 1,
            baseConversionRate: 1,
            _id: 1,
          },
        }, {
          path: 'uomBuy',
          select: {
            name: 1,
            nameAr: 1,
            measure: 1,
            baseConversionRate: 1,
            _id: 1,
          },
        },
        {
          path: 'glMaterialCodeId',
          select: {
            name: 1,
            nameAr: 1,
            _id: 1,
          }
        }],
      },
      {
        path: 'uomBase',
        populate: {
          path: 'baseUnit',
          select: {
            name: 1,
            nameAr: 1,
            measure: 1,
            baseConversionRate: 1,
            _id: 1,
          },
        },
        select: {
          name: 1,
          nameAr: 1,
          _id: 1,
        },
      }

    ],
    ...paginateOptions,
    ...pagination,
  },
);
```

My material names are alphanumeric like, e.g.

- Butter 1-Gram
- Mixed Spices-Pack250 Gram
- Oreo Bar
- Demo1-100G pack
- Cake1

I'm trying to pass paginateOptions like below

```
paginateOptions {
  pagination: true,
  sortBy: 'materialId.name',
  sortDirection: 1,
  limit: 20,
  page: 1
}
```

sortDirection asc or desc - none of is working, can anyone suggest me code here?